# Support folding Pug blocks in Vue in VS Code

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code, pug, code-folding, vue-sfc

Is there a way to get VS Code to support folding blocks within Pug when used in Vue single-file components? That is:

```
<template lang="pug"
...
</template>
```

Comment: It already does support this ([screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/5ZDgMGu)).

Comment: Hmm, it doesn't for me. Can you tell me how to enable it?

Comment: See my answer - seems to be related to Vetur.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on [this bug report](https://github.com/vuejs/vetur/issues/2308) the fact VS Code isn't doing this already seems to be do with using Vetur.

Adding this to settings.json fixed it:

```
    "[vue]": {
        "editor.foldingStrategy": "indentation",
    }
```

Comment: This was driving me nuts—thanks for asking and answering.